# How to make MiniTests run tests in alphabetical order of Test classes?

Tags: minitest, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In MiniTest I know that we can make test methods run in alphabetical order, but its not feasible with the test classes . Is there any way in which we can make MiniTest run in alphabetical order of Test classes?

I know there shouldn't be any dependency between test classes as it is not a good approach, but is there at all any possible way by which we can achieve this?

Comment: Might be possible to do using a Minitest extension, which would enforce the test order. Just an idea, haven't really thought if it's possible to implement.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by using a minitest extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out the solution just in case anyone is looking for one

Take a look at the following thread:

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/514

Here is a gist from the thread just in case the link is broken:

> Correct. As you can see in your gist, the test methods are still running in alphabetical order, but the test classes are not.
>
> Test order dependencies are bugs in your tests that can and will lead to errors in production code. You should seriously consider fixing your tests so that each one is order independent. Full randomization with 100% success should be your goal. If you have a lot of tests, this can be a daunting task, but https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-bisect can absolutely help with that.
>
> If you're for some reason absolutely 100% dead-set on keeping your test order dependency (errors), you'll have to monkey patch Minitest.__run.

Add a initializer patching Minitest similar to the following

```
module Minitest
  def self.__run reporter, options
    suites = Runnable.runnables
    parallel, other = suites.partition { |s| s.test_order == :parallel }
    random, sorted  = other.partition  { |s| s.test_order == :random }

    sorted.map { |suite| suite.run reporter, options } +
      random.shuffle.map   { |suite| suite.run reporter, options } +
      parallel.shuffle.map { |suite| suite.run reporter, options }
  end
end
```